# How to ask macports to wrap openmpi with intel compilers?

Tags: c++, macports, openmpi, icc, mpic++

I used MacPorts to install **openmpi**. However, I realized when I use **mpicxx**, it actually uses clang at the backend. I want it to wrap with intel compiler (i.e. icpc). I checked the **openmpi** website but didn't figure out how to do this.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: MacPorts seems really old-school. Any reason for choosing that over [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)? That package manager gives you a lot more control, and the recipes are easily viewed so you can quickly review to find options.

Comment: Oh.. I just thought port and brew perform in a similar way. But is it possible for me to specify intel compiler when installing openmpi using homebrew?

Comment: Homebrew has a lot more in the way of options, plus if you don't like how it's compiling you code, you can fork the recipe and fix it so it works the way you want. That's the real advantage.

Comment: I tried homebrew, but it still wraps with clang. I do not have option to choose different c++ compilers. Sad...

Comment: That's where forking the recipe and adjusting it to suit your needs is a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's spelled out in the docs:

- OpenMPI: https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps

Set the environment variable `OMPI_CXX` (or perhaps just `CXX`) before invoking `mpicxx` or `mpic++`.

- MPICH: https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www1/mpicxx.html

> **-cxx=name**
>
> Use compiler name instead of the default choice. Use this only if the compiler is compatible with the MPICH library (see below)

or

> The environment variables MPICH_CXX may be used to select different C++ compiler and linker.

Comment: the question is about `Open MPI` and this answer is about `MPICH`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: Good catch, OP accepted it regardless.  I've added details for OpenMPI now.

Comment: Keep in mind this is only guaranteed to work if the MPI C++ bindings are **not** used. Otherwise, that will only work if the compilers used to build the MPI library and the user app are *enough* compatible.